# Autocomplete with usefieldArray with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm having issue for Autocomplete and usefieldArray. When I try to append the value from the first input it duplicate to the next append default values. Hope someone can help me on this matter. My codesandbox url is here

for live result  I have codesandbox.io for your reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hoover-kbnwx8?file=/src/App.js:0-8166

Hope someone can help me on this thanks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

import { MDBCol, MDBInput, MDBRow } from "mdb-react-ui-kit";
import { FaTrashAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);
  const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
  const [itemservice, setitemService] = useState([]);

  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    // Other input fields in the form
    id: "",
    item: "",
    price: "",
    uom_name: "",
    subtotal: ""
  });

  const data_json = [
    {
      id: 45,
      sku: "00001278",
      product_name: "Acetelyn",
      price: "100.0",
      category_id: 1,
      supplier_id: 1,
      status: "active",
      updated_at: "2007-01-21T06:56:00.000Z",
      company_name: "KRIS LPG",
      category_name: "Petron Gasul",
      quantity: "0.0",
      buy_price: "40.0",
      brand: "KRIS",
      on_po_received: 0,
      uom_name: "meter",
      ratio: "1.0",
      po_uom: "1.0",
      uom_selling: "cylinder"
    },
    {
      id: 44,
      sku: "00001277",
      product_name: "Argon",
      price: "100.0",
      category_id: 1,
      supplier_id: 1,
      status: "active",
      updated_at: "2007-01-21T06:56:00.000Z",
      company_name: "KRIS LPG",
      category_name: "Petron Gasul",
      quantity: "0.0",
      buy_price: "40.0",
      brand: "KRIS",
      on_po_received: 0,
      uom_name: "meter",
      ratio: "1.0",
      po_uom: "1.0",
      uom_selling: "cylinder"
    }
  ];

  const data = data_json.map((item) => item);

  const getItem = () => {
    setitemService(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItem();
  }, []);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputValue(value);

    const filteredSuggestions = data.filter((item) =>
      item.product_name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );

    setSuggestions(filteredSuggestions);
  };

  const handleSuggestionSelect = (item) => {
    setInputValue(item.product_name);
    setSelectedItem(item);

    // Update other input fields based on selected item
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      id: item.id,
      uom_name: item.uom_name,
      price: item.price
      // ...
    });

    setSuggestions([]);
  };

  const onClick = (e) => {
    setActive(0);
    setSuggestions([]);
    setIsShow(false);
    setInputValue([e.currentTarget.innerText]);
  };

  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      // enter key
      setActive(0);
      setIsShow(false);
      setInputValue(suggestions[active].product_name);
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        id: suggestions[active].id
        // ...
      });

      // Clear suggestions
      setSuggestions([]);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      // up arrow
      return active === 0 ? null : setActive(active - 1);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      // down arrow
      return active - 1 === suggestions.length ? null : setActive(active + 1);
    }
  };

  const quantity = (e) => {
    const input_qty = e.target.value;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      quantity: input_qty,
      subtotal: input_qty * formData.price
    });
  };

  const [parts, setParts] = useState([
    {
      item: "",
      quantity: "",
      price: 0.0,
      product_id: "",
      uom: "",
      subtotal: 0.0
    }
  ]);

  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    getValues,
    setValue,
    reset,
    initialState
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      itemslist: [
        {
          pid: "",
          item: "",
          quantity: "",
          price: 0.0,
          subtotal: 0.0
        }
      ]
      // itemslist: parts
    }
  });

  const {
    fields: itemFields,
    append: itemAppend,
    remove: itemRemove
  } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "itemslist" });

  console.log(itemFields);
  return (
    <>
      <table className="table tablesorter-metro-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>PO Quantity</th>
            <th>UOM</th>
            {/* <th>On Hand</th> */}
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {itemFields.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>
                <MDBInput
                  type="text"
                  value={inputValue}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                  className="form-control"
                  name={`itemslist[${index}].item`}
                />

                <input
                  type="hidden"
                  className="form-control"
                  name={`itemslist[${index}].id`}
                  value={formData.id}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setFormData({ ...formData, id: e.target.value })
                  }
                />
                <ul className="autocomplete">
                  {suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
                    let className;
                    if (suggestion.id) {
                      className = "active";
                    }
                    return (
                      <li
                        className={className}
                        key={suggestion.id}
                        onClick={() => handleSuggestionSelect(suggestion)}
                      >
                        {suggestion.product_name}
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
                </ul>
              </td>

              <td>
                <MDBInput
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name={`itemslist[${index}].quantity`}
                  onChange={(e) => quantity(e)}
                />
              </td>

              <td>
                <MDBInput
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name={`itemslist[${index}].uom_name`}
                  value={formData.uom_name}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setFormData({ ...formData, uom_name: e.target.value })
                  }
                />
              </td>

              <td>
                <MDBInput
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name={`itemslist[${index}].price`}
                  value={formData.price}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setFormData({ ...formData, price: e.target.value })
                  }
                />
              </td>

              <td>
                <MDBInput
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name={`itemslist[${index}].subtotal`}
                  value={formData.subtotal}
                  // onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, price: e.target.value })}
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <Button
                  size="xs"
                  // rightIcon={<FaTrashAlt />}
                  onClick={() => itemRemove(index)}
                  className="remove-btn"
                >
                  <FaTrashAlt /> {}
                </Button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol className=" mt-4 mb-3">
          <Button
            type="button"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              itemAppend({
                item: "",
                quantity: "",
                price: "",
                subtotal: "0.00"
              });
            }}
          >
            +
          </Button>
        </MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>



      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol className=" mt-4 mb-3">Grand Total:</MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```